# PHP self-hosted markdown editor

Tags: php, self-hosted, markdown

I'm looking for a self hosted markdown editor in PHP with a few special features.

**Requirements**

- Self hosted PHP
- A file tree to the left with the possibility to create new files and folders
- Load and save files
- Split screen view with markdown on one side and rendered html live on the other

**Bonus**

- Custom style.css file to control the look of the output
- Image drag and drop support
- More file operations like rename and delete
- It's good if it's free but it's not required

Comment: Would you do with a Javascript-based alternative?

Comment: Then I can't save the file to the server.

Comment: why can't you? What's stopping you?

Comment: @Sonamor Javascript can't write to the server.